# Calculating your date of birth in Java

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to create a program which works out how many days you've lived for. The code below is as far as I've got to. Is there a certain date type for a variable to store your date of birth?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Date CurrentDate = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    int day;        
    int month;
    int year;
    int noofDaysOld = 0;

    System.out.println("Age Calculator");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current Date: "+ dateFormat.format(CurrentDate));
    System.out.println("Find out how many days you have lived for");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Input your date of birth");
    System.out.println("Day (of month e.g. 4th)");
    day = Input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Month (no e.g. 1: January)");
    month = Input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Year");
    year = Input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    noofDaysOld = CalculateDayAge(day, month, year);
    System.out.println("You age in days is: "+noofDaysOld);        
}    
    public static int CalculateDayAge(int dayNo, int monthNo, int yearAD){
        Date DateofBirth;
        DateofBirth;
        return DayAge;
    }
```

}

Comment: If you're using Java 8, I'd strongly advise you to use `LocalDate`. If you're not, use Joda Time and *its* `LocalDate` class... (Now would also be a good time to look up Java naming conventions...)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked up Joda Time and found how to convert the date class to DateTime class. Code: import java.util.Date juDate = new Date();. In the Main Method: DateTime dt = new DateTime(juDate); . The problem I had there was that it gave an error. How can you use it in Java Netbeans IDE 7.2 with Joda Time without error?

Comment: @GeorgeT97 See 2nd method in my answer for Joda-Time implementation. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, the built-in [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is the easiest to use.

If not on Java 8, the easiest is to use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Otherwise, you have to use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object. Using the Calendar object is more complicated, because the two dates you'll be comparing (birthday vs today) may be in different [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) "zones". This can be accomodated by calculating the number of milliseconds between the two (pure) dates and dividing by 24 hours, *rounding* the result such that both 23, 24, and 25 hours becomes 1 day.

Here are the 3 implementations, using Java 8, Joda-Time, and Calendar, respectively. Code uses full qualification because of name clash.

```
public static int calculateDayAge1(int dayNo, int monthNo, int yearAD) {
    // Use Java 8 LocalDate
    java.time.LocalDate birthDate = java.time.LocalDate.of(yearAD, monthNo, dayNo);
    java.time.LocalDate today = java.time.LocalDate.now();
    long days = birthDate.until(today, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    return (int)days;
}

public static int calculateDayAge2(int dayNo, int monthNo, int yearAD) {
    // Use Joda-Time LocalDate
    org.joda.time.LocalDate birthDate = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(yearAD, monthNo, dayNo);
    org.joda.time.LocalDate today = org.joda.time.LocalDate.now();
    org.joda.time.Days days = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween(birthDate, today);
    return days.getDays();
}

public static int calculateDayAge3(int dayNo, int monthNo, int yearAD) {
    // Get today/now to millisecond precision
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    // Get millis for today at midnight (make it a pure date)
    int todayYear  = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
    int todayMonth = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
    int todayDay   = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay);
    long todayMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Get millis for birthdate
    cal.set(yearAD, monthNo - 1, dayNo);
    long birthdayMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Calculate number of 24 hour days between birthdate and today,
    // rounding the result to account for daylight savings time discrepancies
    final long millisPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 86400000
    long days = (todayMillis - birthdayMillis + millisPerDay / 2) / millisPerDay;
    return (int)days;
}
```

Testing the code using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Today is: " + java.time.LocalDate.now());
    System.out.println("Age (in days) of Scott McNealy, co-founder of Sun Microsystems (born November 13, 1954):");
    System.out.println(calculateDayAge1(13, 11, 1954));
    System.out.println(calculateDayAge2(13, 11, 1954));
    System.out.println(calculateDayAge3(13, 11, 1954));
}
```

produces this output:

```
Today is: 2015-09-07
Age (in days) of Scott McNealy, co-founder of Sun Microsystems (born November 13, 1954):
22213
22213
22213
```

Comment: Good work, but I suggest passing a time zone object to those calls to `now()`. The time zone is crucial in determining a date. When omitted, the JVM's current default time zone is silently applied. That value may vary, so I suggest always specifying your desired/expected time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque The question is not how old the person is if he/she were in Sydney (for example), but how old the person is as of now where I am, which is what the default timezone indicates. The thought of using a different time zone makes no sense, unless you also have the time zone of where the person was born, and the exact time of birth.

Comment: If you truly want the default time zone, I suggest calling for it explicitly with `::getDefault` to make the code self-documenting. But besides that, you assume the JVM's current default is actually set to the one you want. But the current default time zone can change at any moment during runtime! Any code in any thread of any app can change the current default for the entire JVM with a simple call to `TimeZone.setDefault`. Moving between machines or admins may mean a different time zone. Servers are often set to UTC. I've had to set a server to Alberta CA time for technical workaround.

Comment: @BasilBourque You may be right for *some* server software, but if not using the local machine time zone, where should you get it from? And if a VM runs multiple applications and one of those applications change the time zone, it should be shot and killed on the spot, as well as the developer, manager, designer, and tester of the software. But that's not here nor there, because *this* question is a standalone Java program (see `main` method in question), and the problems you are raising are so very *very* far beyond the scope of the question, you can't even see it on the horizon.

Comment: Agreed, the default time zone in JVM should only be changed as a last resort, yet you'll see it suggested quite often here on StackOverflow. As for where to get time zone, easy: If you are in Montreal and expect a Montreal time zone say `DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" )`. As for being in the scope, this question is aimed at neophytes learning the basics of handling date-time work. I believe this implicit defaulting of time zone to be one of the major causes of trouble and frustrating bugs for those learning date-time work. So I consider the issue very important for their edification.